# Strings containing duplicate characters for if statements in Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, duplicates

I am trying to use `if` statements to check for the presence of a particular string which also happens to be with the same file name. However, I have come across two strings that have common characters and I would like to strictly not check for duplicates. Here is the part of my code. I have two files named `p_rgh_0` and `h_0`.

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(logsDir, topdown=False):
for lf in sorted(files):
    if (plot_pressure or plot_all):
        if any( (filename in lf) for filename in ('p_0', 'p_rgh_0') ):
            logFile = os.path.join(path, lf)
            data = np.loadtxt(logFile)
            time, value = data[:,0], data[:,1]
            (time, value, lf) = pressure(time, value, lf)
    if (plot_enthalpy):
        if any( (filename in lf) for filename in ('h_0') ):
            print lf
            logFile = os.path.join(path, lf)
            data = np.loadtxt(logFile)
            time, value = data[:,0], data[:,1]
            (time, value, lf) = enthalpy(time, value, lf)
```

Now since `h_0` is a common string, both files are being processed in the second `if` statement where I check exclusively only for `h_0`. The `print lf` prints both the files, however it should be only `h_0`. Is there a way to eliminate this behaviour and only check for `h_0`?

Comment: Can you test using `==` instead of `in` or are there indeed cases where you need a substring of the file name to work?

Comment: I do not actually need a substring of the file name to work. For example `p_rgh_0`  and `h_0` are totally different. I can use `==` such as, `if lf == 'hf'`, however I may increase the list of strings in future, so that I have many more starting with `h` including `h_0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `continue` statement in the first block processing `pressure()` to ensure any dual matching files don't get processed in `enthalpy()` calls.